# How to add `colorbar` to `networkx` using a `seaborn` color palette? (Python 3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, networkx, seaborn

I'm trying to add a `colorbar` to my `networkx` drawn `matplotlib ax` from the range of `1` (being the lightest) and `3` (being the darkest) [check out the line w/ `cmap` below]. I'm trying to combine a lot of `PyData` functionalities.

**How can I add a color bar type feature on a networkx plot using a seaborn color palette?**

[image]

```
# Set up Graph
DF_adj = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
     [[1, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 1] ]), columns=['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'], index=['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])

G = nx.Graph(DF_adj.as_matrix())
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(zip(range(4), ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])))

# Color mapping
color_palette = sns.cubehelix_palette(3)
cmap = {k:color_palette[v-1] for k,v in zip(['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'],[2, 1, 3, 2])}

# Draw
nx.draw(G, node_color=[cmap[node] for node in G.nodes()], with_labels=True)
```

In this, they are all using `matplotlib` color palettes: http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut3.html  I even tried converting them to a `ListedColormap` object but it didn't work.

This doesn't work for my situation either b/c matplotlib colormap: [Seaborn regplot with colorbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353363/seaborn-regplot-with-colorbar)

Same for http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html

This was the closest I got but it didn't work I got a autoscale Nonetype: [How do I use seaborns color_palette as a colormap in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902459/how-do-i-use-seaborns-color-palette-as-a-colormap-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Doesn't `nx.draw` return the artists created?

Comment: `nx.draw` doesn't return anything (at least not in this case), which is why I went with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do here is to fake it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11558629/5285918) since you don't have a "ScalarMappable" to work with.

For a discrete colormap

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=ListedColormap(color_palette),
                           norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

If you want a linear (continuous) colormap and to only show integer ticks

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(3, as_cmap=True),
                           norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=range(4))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get integer values and make it continuous in this way?

Comment: hey @lanery thanks for the answer/update.  I'm going to test this when I get to my computer tomorrow morning and then Approve it!

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks a lot @lanery.  Why did you do `sm._A = []`?

Comment: Also, I put a follow up question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646027/how-to-stop-colorbar-from-reshaping-networkx-plot-python-3 w/ a shoutout to you for the `colorbar` in case you might have some insight.

Comment: That was borrowed from the answer I linked to, but it's basically to prevent a `TypeError` that is raised when the colorbar tries to autoscale.

Comment: Is there any way to append it to an already made plot instead of merging it?

Comment: See my answer on your follow up question.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed it.  I was trying to do `fig_2, ax_2 = plt.subplots(ncols=2)` then `ax_2[0] = ax` to store the old ax on a new figure