# How to stop `colorbar` from reshaping `networkx` plot? (Python 3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, networkx, colorbar

I am trying to change the `colorbar` on my `networkx` plot.  The bar gets extra wide and also smooshes my original `networkx` plot (left) when I add the `colorbar` on there (right).

**How can I make my `colorbar` thinner and not alter my original `networkx` graph?**

My code below with `colorbar` courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/users/5285918/lanery but used w/ a larger network.

```
# Set up Graph
DF_adj = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
     [[1, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 1] ]), columns=['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'], index=['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])

G = nx.Graph(DF_adj.as_matrix())
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(zip(range(4), ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])))

# Color mapping
color_palette = sns.cubehelix_palette(3)
cmap = {k:color_palette[v-1] for k,v in zip(['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'],[2, 1, 3, 2])}

# Draw
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw(G, node_color=[cmap[node] for node in G.nodes()], with_labels=True, ax=ax)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=ListedColormap(color_palette),
                           norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3))
sm._A = []
fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=range(1,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way should be to plot the colorbar on its own axis and play around with the [left, bottom, width, height] parameters.

```
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.015, 0.8])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=ListedColormap(color_palette),
                           norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3))
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cbaxes, ticks=range(4))
```

Source: [positioning the colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310594/positioning-the-colorbar)