# Colormap has wrong range when used with seaborn factegrid and pyplot scatter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For a Pandas dataframe, I am trying to use Seaborn to create a FacetGrid based on one column ('year') and then create a scatter plot for each subplot where the x and y axes correspond to the columns 'x' and 'y' and the color corresponds to yet another value 'p'. *I'm also looking to add a meaningful colorbar as an annotation to the plot.* Using my code below, where `data` is a Pandas dataframe,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# 'data' imported from a csv file
data.head()
          x         y         q         t         p  year
0  0.864721  0.080396  0.970694  0.848008  2.164305     1
1  0.615352  0.768370  0.950874  2.902603  2.383057     3
2  0.775110  0.562287  1.163768  0.151289  4.026925     1
3  0.355569  0.161638  0.840118  3.075967  0.431773     4
4  0.405850  0.807168  1.261452  0.242770  1.111010     1

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col='year', hue='p', palette='seismic')
g = g.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y', s=100, alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar()
```

I am able to create this as pictured below.
[image]

So I can get a facetgrid with scatter plots. **The problem is that my colorbar on the right hand side is not aligned (in terms of values and color palette) with the circles in the scatter plots.** The true values for 'p' range from 0.15 to 8.2; the values for the colormap range from 0 and 1. In addition, the color palette seems to differ between the plots and the colormap. So a correct colormap would range from dark blue to dark red for the range 0.15 to 8.2.

I suspect that the colormap I'm creating is not "linked" to the scatter plots. Instead, pyplot is just creating a generic colormap with a default palette and range in the absence of any data to use.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seaborn regplot with colorbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353363/seaborn-regplot-with-colorbar)